# Why an object key's first value is treated as a string - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, key

I have an object named as "param" and it has a key named as "item[]". The values of item[] are inserted dynamically.

Problem is when "item[]" has a single value, it treats that value as a string and not as first index of array.

Example :

```
item[]="123";
```

but when it has multiple values then it treats itself as an array which is desired, example-

```
item[] = ["123","456"];
```

I want the single value also as index of this array like

```
item[] = ["123"]
```

How would I do it ?

P.S. - This object is created from querystring parameters like http://example.com/def?item[]=123&item[]=456, then when I extract querystring, it returns these parameters as the keys of an object

I am extracting querystring in this way(Javascript)-

```
var param = $location.search();
console.log('Param');      
console.log(param);//Returns Object{item[]=[2]} in console
```

Comment: So where does this object come from or how is it created? Really hard to help without more context. Also what is significance of using `[]` in property name?

Comment: Updated the question @charlietfl

Comment: you can't just write item[]="123"; in javascript it will give Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [(…)

Comment: I am actually not writing it. It returns the value like that when the URL has a single query parameter. Like  http://example.com/def?item[]=123

Comment: *"then when I extract querystring"* ...where's that code?...obviously it's the part that needs modifying.

Comment: Updated with the code @charlietfl

Comment: push values in an array Item.push(queryStringValue) and clear item values  respectively

Comment: @MahanteshKumbar.. If I push values in array then it would go like this arr["123",["345","876"],["789","783","341"]] and I don't want this. I want values in the form like arr["123","761","671"].. like this

Comment: For single value just push directly into an array and for multiple values loop over the array and push values one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it -

```
if(typeof param['item[]'] == "string"){
    param['item[]'] = [param['item[]']];
}
```

First I am checking if the key has a string value, if it is string then I am converting it into an array and it worked.

Here is the working fiddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/r3vrxzup/

Answer (score 3):

This is because `variableName[]` is not a javascript syntax.
Since it does not recognise the [], it is probably part of the name if it does not throw an error.

To create an array, you have 2 possibilities :

```
//Contsructor
var ar = new Array(); //empty array
//Literal
var ar = []; //same as above
var ar = [0,1,2,3]; //array of length 4
var ar = new Array(4); //empty array of length 4
```

to access or set it

```
var ar[0] = "value"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
queryString = ["123"];
queryString = ["123","432","456"];
if(queryString.length==1){
   item.push(queryString[0]);
}else{
  angular.forEach(queryString,function(value,key){
       item.push(value);//push only value
  })
}
```